# Vue route-link is not working for root '/' path

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This is my `router` config:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            redirect: { name: 'auth.login' },
        },
        {
            path: '/auth/login',
            name: 'auth.login',
            component: () => import('@/pages/Auth/LoginPage.vue'),
        },
        {
            path: '/auth/registration',
            name: 'auth.registration',
            component: () => import('@/pages/Auth/RegistrationPage.vue'),
        },
    ],
});
```

Next, I have `Logo` component that acts as link to the home page:

```
<template>
    <div class="logo">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }" exact>Uhire</router-link>
    </div>
</template>
```

However, clicking on `Logo` component in browser doesn't do anything (nothing happens, even url string is not changed).

But if I change `href` from `home` to `auth.registration` everything works.

What might be a reason for such behavior?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to redirect to the url redirect: '/auth/login', let's see if that will work.

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel what you suggested is what I had initially - this is not working

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a tad old, and your problem may be different from mine, but mine resulted from a navigation guard.

In my route, I had a beforeEnter guard on the "/" path:

```
beforeEnter: (from, to, next) => {
  if (!userToken || !publicKey) next("/login");
},
```

This caused the router not to go to "/".

I then remembered the admonishment from the docs:

> Make sure that the next function is called exactly once in any given
> pass through the navigation guard. It can appear more than once, but
> only if the logical paths have no overlap, otherwise the hook will
> never be resolved or produce errors.

Lo and behold, I modified my code (exactly as the docs recommended ... because I'm a special kind of slow) :p and it worked:

```
beforeEnter: (from, to, next) => {
  if (!userToken || !publicKey) next("/login");

  next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the Logo component like this:

```html
<template>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#" @click="navigateTo({name: 'root'})">Uhire</a>
    </div>
</template>
```

And add the script bellow like this:

```html
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      navigateTo (route) {
        this.$router.push(route)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```